# Android whatsapp attachment icon

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

1) when I use some apps to send a file to whatsapp directly, there is an icon text (DB) and extra text under the icon (DB). pls see below pic. However, my code below gives me plain icon (without DB) and without extra text
[image: whatsapp attachment]

```
        Uri lvUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(pActivity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", pFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(pAction);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {  });
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "EXTRA_TEXT");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, lvUri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setType("application/xml");
```

2) is there any way to send an attachment together with a message at the same time?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw over using a suitable Layout like RelativeLayout.

Using ImageView and TextView, it is possible to have such result.

Comment: sorry. i am not mimicing whatsapp, i mean the sending real file to whatsapp